# How to commit changes made to docker image

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code

I am very new to docker and have had help from a friend to set up a hasura instance that uses action handlers (node app).

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml

version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.3
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      # ... my config
  actions:
    build:
      context: ./action-handlers
      dockerfile: .docker/${DOCKERFILE}
    depends_on:
      - "hasura"
    volumes:
      - actions:/./app
    environment:
      # ...my confg
  hasura:
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 9691:9691
    build:
      context: ./hasura
      dockerfile: .docker/${DOCKERFILE}
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    environment:
      # ...my config

volumes:
  db_data:
  actions:
```

This config works great. I am using VScode so naturally followed their [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) on how to develop when using containers. It recommends to use their [Remove Development pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack), which I have done and I can make changes, the app responds to code changes and everything works as expected.

However I can't seem to find a way to easily commit my changes to git. Here is how my repo (`my-project`) is structure:

```
my-project
├── action-handlers
│   └── files folders for my node app
├── hasura
│   └── files folders for the hasura instance
├── README.md
├── docker-compose.yml
├── .github
└── .env
```

So when the images are running and I open the `action-handlers` folder in the image to make changes, the `git` folder isn't present so I can't save my changes. I have to copy them across to another VSCode workspace with the `my-project` repo just so I can commit them. When I am making several changes this becomes annoying very quickly.

Is this expected? Or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: I'd recommend reversing the logic, make changes to the source and rebuild the container from a new image (built by with a Dockerfile). For iterative development, you'll often see a volume mount of the source code into the container being developed.

Comment: Are you able to share an example of how I could do this?

Comment: It varies by language. Here's a nodejs example from docker (note the `.:/app` volume): https://docs.docker.com/language/nodejs/develop/